# Python - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Im trying to output a feature map from the weights output by my CNN. 
[Full code can be found here.](https://pastebin.com/Xm3Mp6BQ)

When I try to run the function below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as cm

def plot_filters(layer, x, y):

filters = layer.get_weights()
fig = plt.figure()

for j in range(len(filters)):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(y, x, j+1)
    ax.matshow(filters[j][0], cmap = cm.binary)
    plt.xticks(np.array([]))
    plt.yticks(np.array([]))

plt.tight_layout()
```

I get the following TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PATH\Code\CNN.py", line 85, in <module>
plot_filters(model.layers[0], 8, 4)
File "PATH\Code\CNN.py", line 21, in plot_filters
ax.matshow(filters[j][0], cmap = plt.cm.binary)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64     \lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 7841, in matshow
nr, nc = Z.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I ran `print(filters[j][0].shape)` which outputs `(3, 1, 32)`
The images in my dataset are 20x20x1 and below is a snippet of the summary of my model.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 9, 9, 32)          320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 9, 9, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
```

Any help on how i can show feature maps will be appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: If `print(filters[j][0].shape)` returns a tuple with 3 elements, you need to store each element in a variable, but you are only using two variables

Comment: @AaronGarton can you elaborate more on what you mean?

Comment: Matshow can plot 2D arrays. `(3, 1, 32)` is 3D. You cannot plot a 3D array with matshow.

Comment: The `print` outputs `(3, 1, 32)`, which means that it is a 2D array. You are trying to pass a 3D array to a function that calls for a 2D array. See https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.matshow.html

Comment: Have any idea on how to do this? been trying for a couple hours and cant seem to get past either too many values or too few values error.

Comment: @AaronGarton thanks for your help! figured it out :) (took me a while haha)